# PersistenceException: when using @OneToMany

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, playframework, one-to-many

I am trying to create my database with JPA and MYSQL using play framework, but i'am getting the following error when mapping a @oneToMany

```
    PersistenceException: Error with the Join on [models.Patient.progress].
    Could not find the matching foreign key for [id] in table[Results]? 
    Perhaps using a @JoinColumn with the name/referencedColumnName attributes swapped?
```

My classes looks as following:

**Patient**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Patients")
public class Patient
    extends User {


 @Id
 @Column(name = "idPatient")
 private int idPatient;
 @Constraints.Required
 private String medicalCoverage;
 @Constraints.Required
 private String disease;
 @Constraints.Required
 private int gradeDisease;
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "patient",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private List<Results> progress;
 @ManyToMany
 @JoinTable(name = "therapist_relation",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "idPatient")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "idTherapist")})
 private List<Therapist> therapists;
 private int qAwardA;
 private int qAwardB;
 private int qAwardC;
```

**Result**

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Results")
 public class Results {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "idResult")
  private int idResult;
  private Game game;
  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="idPatient", referencedColumnName = "idPatient", nullable = false)
  private Patient patient;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name="idTherapist", referencedColumnName = "idResult")
  private Therapist therapist;
  private int punctuation;
  private String description;
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with @JoinColumn annotation for `Patient` in class `Results`.

You are using `referencedColumnName` parameter.

Following documentation:

> (Optional) The name of the column referenced by this foreign key
>   column.

So, in this case this argument is not necessary. If you want use it should look like `referencedColumnName = "idResult"` but as I said it's not necessary.

Comment: if i make what you say i am havin this new error: PersistenceException: Error with the Join on [models.Results.patient]. Could not find the local match for [null] Perhaps an error in a @JoinColumn